# change bootstrap row padding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I try to use a custom css property for a bootstrap row that I want to remove the padding in the bottom. But this has no effect at all. What do I need to change in order to make it work?

```
<!-- Begin .row -->
<div class="row row-no-padding" style="background-color: #CCC; padding-bottom: 0!important">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <button type="button" class="btn_submit_quick_search btn_submit_search pull-right" style="margin-bottom: 20px;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">read more</button>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End .row -->
```

Comment: `.row{padding: 0 !important; }` ?

Comment: Sorry, no effect at all...

Comment: Rows do not have padding in bootstrap, but they do have magin-bottom, so try margin-botttom:0; Also dont do this on global level, you will have problems in the future if you do.

Comment: Hmm, the suggestied solutions does not affect anything...

Comment: go into inspect element and check what is causing the problem

Comment: Can you send all code ? I see that you have only margin-button 20px for button and that cause space between elements.

Comment: In Bootstrap css there is define .row {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
} **no padding** so you can adjust according you want. and **.col-lg-12** class has padding.

Comment: .col-lg-12 only has a padding-left and -right of 15px... there is no padding-bottom or margin-bottom, too.

Comment: @J.Sadi you are mentioning a column class, not a row class.

Comment: @MarkoManojlovic i took notice of Raeesh Alams answer.. ;)

Comment: did my solution worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

Thats the .row style of bootstrap.css:

```
.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

There is no margin-bottom or padding-bottom as you can see.
But you've set a margin-bottom to your button... ;)

```
<button class="btn_submit_quick_search btn_submit_search pull-right" style="margin-bottom: 20px;" type="button" data-target="#collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse">read more</button>
```

Remove style="margin-bottom: 20px;" and there will be no more margin "inside your row"

Working solution: http://www.bootply.com/20TUhhuUcG

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution.....

```
        <style type="text/css">
            .row-no-padding,.row-no-padding div,.row-no-padding div button{
                padding: 0 !important;
            }
        </style>

        <div class="row row-no-padding" style="background-color: #CCC; padding-bottom: 0 !important">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <button type="button" class="btn_submit_quick_search btn_submit_search pull-right" style="margin-bottom: 0px;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">read more</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Replace this code

Comment: the class .row has no padding.. why should he use "padding: 0 !important"? the only reason why your solution is working, is that you've set the margin-bottom form the button to 0px.... and that was the issue which iv'e reffered to in my answer, one houre ago.